# Security in Android Application

Tags: android, android-security

I am working on the android application and I want to make the app more secure, so I would like to know the different types of security measures can be added to the application to make the app secure?

Comment: Secure from what? This seems overly broad without specifying what type of threats you are worried about.

Comment: 1.Network security 2.Storing data internally like password 3.reverse engineering

Answer (score 1):

Google have created set of tips to optimism your app for security on bellow link.

https://developer.android.com/topic/security/best-practices

Comment: what about encription and progaurd and other techniques.Is there any other method apart from android techniques

Comment: If you are to serious and want more security you can go for dexguard paid version of proguard.  https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard

Comment: If you want to encrypt your database go for SQLCipher   https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/